# How to Buy/Sell tokens using Uniswap V3 Multicall function?

Tags: web3js, ether, etherscan, web3.py, uniswap

I used to create programs to buy and sell tokens by interacting directly with Uniswap V2 router functions (SwapExactEthForTokens, and others). It was fairly simple because all I needed to do was to input the amount and address. Now that there's V3, I have no idea how to get my inputs into the "Multicall" function.

[image: Transaction attempt]

[image: Function]

How do I convert into or decode these Hex data I've taken from transactions? Thank you for all the help in advance.

Comment: one way is via another smartcontract (problem, need to delegate token aprove etc..,  im find way JS